# RegEx Dollar validation

Tags: regex

I've seen several posts about validating dollar amounts with RegEx and I'm pretty close to what I need but with one issue.  Here is what I have so far

```
^[\+\-]?\$?(\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Here is what it accomplishes:

- Leading Trailing Space not allowed
- Positive/Negative at beginning is optional
- Dollar Sign is optional
- Commas are optional but if they exist ○ need to be followed by 3
  digits and preceded with 1 to 3 digits
- Decimal Point is optional but if exists: 1) No digits are required before the decimal point 2) 1 or more digits are required after a decimal point

All these conditions are met but the issue I'm having is that if the user enters only a `+`, `-`, or `$` then the expression returns true. What I'm looking for is if `$+-` exist they must be followed by something.

I know the issue is that a number before a decimal is optional, and the decimal section itself is also optional.  But I want to allow entry of `.25` w/o having to force it to be entered as `0.25`.

I tried adding not end of line `[^$]` after the optional dollar sign `\$?` thinking that the `+-$` couldn't be followed by end of line, but that didn't seem to work.

I appreciate any help!

-Shawn

Comment: `^[+-]?\$?(?=.)(\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(.[0-9]+)?$` , use look ahead https://regex101.com/r/iE6jM9/1

Comment: Perfect Answer Thanks!  I'm fairly new to RegEx and hadn't used the look ahead assertion before.

Comment: but it will do the trick ;)

Comment: or `^[+-]?\$?(\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(.[0-9]+)?$` , change `\d*` to `\d+`

Comment: Sorry you need to escape `.` .. `^[+-]?\$?(?=.)(\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.[0-9]+)?$` or `^[+-]?\$?(\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: That wouldn't work because the requirement is that they can enter decimals w/o digits preceding.  I think your first answer using the look ahead assertion is the way to go.  :o)

Comment: Yes the following are all allowed `.25` `+.25` `-.25` `$.25` `-$.25` `+$.25`

Comment: `^[+-]?\$?(?=.)(?:\d*|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.[0-9]+)?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the following regex

1. `\d*` is causing the problem, so  use look ahead assertion. It confirms that there will be at least one character after the symbols
2. You need to escape `.`, use `\.` instead else it will match any character

**Regex :**

```
^[+-]?\$?(?=.)(?:\d*|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.[0-9]+)?$
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/iE6jM9/4)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: This doesn't work for the solution because the following need to be allowed `.25` `+.25` `-.25` `$.25` `-$.25` `+$.25`

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `\d*`, in:

```
^[\+\-]?\$?(\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.[0-9]+)?$
              ^here
```

replacing it with `+` seems to ensure at least one digit is entered.

```
^[\+\-]?\$?(\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

This ensures the `+`, `-` or `$` is followed by at least one digit.

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fD5oZ6/1)

A potential problem is that `$.25` will not match, you can resolve this however with:

```
^[\+\-]?\$?((\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)(\.[0-9]+)?|(\.[0-9]+))$
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/xK7qI7/1)

This regex will work on probably all regex engines. If the engine supports lookahead, you can make it more elegant.